# Why my filter request rewrite each other?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to do script where I can filter users. The problem is where I write one field, then another doesn't work. Always works only one last request, not all. How to change it?

```
if ($request->has('city')) 
{
    $user = User::with('user_data')->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) { 
        return $query->where('residence', $request->city); 
    })->get();
}

if ($request->has('age_from')) 
{
    $user = User::with('user_data')->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) { 
        return $query->where('date_of_birth', '<=', Carbon::now()->subYears($request->age_from)); 
    })->get();
}

if ($request->has('age_to')) 
{
    $user = User::with('user_data')->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) { 
        return $query->where('date_of_birth', '>=', Carbon::now()->subYears($request->age_to)); 
    })->get();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are not in the right way.Questions isn't enough to imagine your problem exactly.

But to fix it,tricks from below might help you.

You can use multiple `whereHas` like this.

```
$user = User::with('user_data')->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) { 
        return $query->where('residence', $request->city); 
    })
    ->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) { 
        return $query->where('date_of_birth', '<=', Carbon::now()->subYears($request->age_from)); 
    })
    ->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) { 
        return $query->where('date_of_birth', '>=', Carbon::now()->subYears($request->age_to)); 
    })->get();
```

If you want to filter it by `$request`, do like this.

```
$user = User::with('user_data');
        if ($request->has('city')) {
            $user->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) {
               return $query->where('residence', $request->city);
           });
        }
        if ($request->has('age_from')) {
            $user->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) {
                return $query->where('date_of_birth', '<=', Carbon::now()->subYears($request->age_from));
            });
        }
        if($request->has('age_to')){
            $user->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) {
                return $query->where('date_of_birth', '>=', Carbon::now()->subYears($request->age_to));
            });
        }
        $user = $user->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, all input field will present in the request when they're not disabled in your HTML, so it is not depending on the field value and your check for **availability** of the input variable using **has()** method always returns **true** for both the filled and blank inputs.

So you need to check for value using input() method.

Furthermore while it is possible to have more than one input value in a request, you need to add your criteria to the model before getting the results:

```
$user = User::with('user_data');
if ($request->input('city')) 
{
    $user->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) { 
        $query->where('residence', $request->city); 
    });
}

if ($request->input('age_from')) 
{
    $user->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) { 
        $query->where('date_of_birth', '<=', Carbon::now()->subYears($request->age_from)); 
    });
}

if ($request->input('age_to')) 
{
    $user->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) { 
        $query->where('date_of_birth', '>=', Carbon::now()->subYears($request->age_to)); 
    });
}
$user = $user->get();
```